# Lets encrypt auto renew not working

Tags: linux, ssl, lets-encrypt

I am getting the following:

```
# ./certbot-auto renue
Error: couldn't get currently installed version for /root/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/letsencrypt:
./certbot-auto: /root/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/letsencrypt: /root/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I have Python2.7 installed but for some reason letsencrypt is not using the correct the file path.

Is this a OS issue?

Comment: Do you have a /root/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/python2.7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/letsencrypt
./certbot-auto
```